# Qtimer not working

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to use `QTimer` to update the GUI with sensor values.

I tried the following very simple code:

```
 from pyQt4 import QtCore
 def f():
   try :
      print ("text")
   finally :
      QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(5000, f)
 f()
```

It's not working.

Comment: you need not use QtCore.QTimer()

Comment: Is that example supposed to be complete? If so, why would you expect it to work?

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyApp(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        self.print_hello()

    def print_hello(self):
        print 'hello'
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(3000, self.print_hello)

qapp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  
app = MyApp()
qapp.exec_()
```

I'm not sure why this works, but it has something to do with that the timer needs to be in running thread. I guess it's created with app object...